# relative path in @nuxtjs/dotenv

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am building an SSR `nuxt.js` project with laravel backend, and I want to share the `.env` for both laravel and nuxt.

Here is my folder structure (base on a laravel folder structure but add a client folder to put nuxt)

[image]

here is my `nuxt.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    srcDir: __dirname,
    buildModules: [
        [
            '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
            {
                path: '../'
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js -c client/nuxt.config.js",
        "build": "node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js build -c client/nuxt.config.js",
        "start": "node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js start -c client/nuxt.config.js",
        "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue client/",
        "prod": "npm run build && npm run start"
    },
    "config": {
        "nuxt": {
            "host": "0.0.0.0",
            "port": "3000"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
        "nuxt": "^2.12.2",
    }
}
```

I want to use a relative path instead of an absolute path, but it doesn't work.
[image]

How can I fix it? Thanks a lot (*^_^*)

Comment: Would using `__dirname/../` help ? Or maybe even `path.dirname(__dirname)`

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks a lot！I fix it by `path: __dirname + '/../'`