# @nuxtjs-dotenv relative paths

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

If have an issue similar to this one [relative path in @nuxtjs/dotenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61337535/relative-path-in-nuxtjs-dotenv)

However the solution is NOT working here.

```
const { join } = require('path')

buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', {path: join(__dirname, '../')}]
  ],
```

I decided to use the path's join function instead of adding the strings together.

If I just print out the `join(__dirname, '../')` it shows the right path, but @nuxtjs/dotenv seems to not move outside it's project directory. Shown bellow is the `console.log()` statement showing the right path. This was printed at the top of the `nuxt.config.js`.

Then, it shows that the path is incorrect and cannot find the `.env` file. This appears to be a bug or something. Several hours on trying to figure out what it's doing. Also, a full path does not work either here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment, as I don't have enough reputation... sorry)

But because you're doing it inside buildModules, wouldn't the __dirname refer to the build directory?